# do_shortcode within post query

Tags: posts, shortcode, query

I am querying blog posts with a specific category (according to the template page slug, and want each post to output a slider, title and content. I'm using the wordpress plugin Anythingslider for Wordpress. I am creating slides with the same category as the post slugs so that everything is automated and less copy and paste - however when I add the do_shortcode line, it duplicates the same post (for as many times as there are posts), instead of displaying EACH post!

Anyone have any ideas?

```
    <?php   
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => $post->post_name,
    'showposts' => 20, 
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

$page_id = get_the_ID();
$page_object = get_page( $page_id ); ?>

<div class="project-column">
    <h4><?php echo $page_object->post_content; ?></h4>
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <div id="navigation">
        <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <a href="#<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>



    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
<div id="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>"></div>
<div class="entry-container">

    <div class="slider-container">
        <?php $shortcode = do_shortcode('[anything_slides cat='.$post->post_name.']');
            echo apply_filters('my_new_filter',$shortcode); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="project-column">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php echo the_content(); ?>            
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What `do_shortcode` line?

Comment: Ahhh... sorry about that. Updated!

Answer (score 1):

You set `$post_slug` outside the Loop, so the value never changes. You need to reset that *inside* the Loop so that it will be reset to each post in turn as the Loop progresses.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
    $the_query->the_post(); 
    $post_slug = $post->post_name;
    echo do_shortcode("[anything_slides cat=".$post_slug."]");
  }
}
```

But there is really no need to set the variable at all. Just use `$post->post_name`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @s-ha-dum! I updated my code with that, except no luck. The page renders 7 posts (I have 7 posts in that category), except all of the same posts display the post title and description of the PAGE that I set the template to.

Comment: Ok basically, something interesting is happening. When I post the do_shortcode for the slider AFTER the post title and content, everything works (the slider only appears once though), but if I post do_shortcode above the title and content, then the issue I mentioned above occurs

Comment: There is  information missing. [Edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/115562/edit) the question with the shortcode callback.

Comment: I added all of the template. First I run a query to display all of the post titles as links. Then I display a query to grab the post info: slider, content and title. If I put the shortcode call above the title and content, then ALL of the posts appear with the title and content from the PAGE that I apply the content to. At the top of the template I call <h4><?php echo $page_object->post_content; ?></h4> the content from the page which the template is applied to, and for some reason the query gets weird and replaces the post content with that description and title.